# JQuery AJAX "Not Found" Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hello Whenever I click on the button that says "Get External Content" I get a javascript alert that says "Not Found" (this is the error's status text).

Why can it not find the text file I am trying to load via ajax?

This is my folder hierarchy:

```
--public_html
  --app
    --ajaxTestHome.php
    --ajaxTestText.txt
```

And this is the file I am trying to load (via ajax) the text file into.

```
//ajaxTestHome.php
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ajax").click(function(){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url:"/app/ajaxTestText.txt", 
                success:function(result){
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }, 
                error: function(abc) {
                    alert(abc.statusText);
                }, 
                cache: false
            }
        );
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

    <button id="ajax">Get External Content</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT: I had a typo in the question. the file is called "ajaxTestText.txt" not "ajaxTestTest.txt"

Comment: Still just remove the /app/. You're looking for ajaxTestText.txt inside /public_html/app/app/ if you do it like this.

Comment: Are you able to request the `.txt` file directly via browser's address bar, `curl`, etc. rather than Ajax? And, how are you accessing the `.php` file? `http://localhost/app/ajaxTestHome.php` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem did not have anything to do with it being in the wrong directory or me referencing the file with or without the "/" or the "/app/" or "app/".

Rather I **changed the extension from .txt to .html**. I was accessing this from a server I was FTPing to, and I guess the server won't correctly let you see/access the contents of a txt file but will an HTML? If you happen to know, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

The URL parameter is incorrect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ajax").click(function(){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url:"ajaxTestText.txt", 
                success:function(result){
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }, 
                error: function(abc) {
                    alert(abc.statusText);
                }, 
                cache: false
            }
        );
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `/app/` in the url.

Also your file is called `ajaxTestTest.txt` and the url you are calling is `ajaxTestText.txt` they have different names

Comment: I tried it without the /app/ and it still said "Not Found". Also the file was actually called "ajaxTestTest.txt". I incorrectly typed it in my question.

Comment: @johnsimer what exactly did you try when you tried it without `/app/`, did you try `ajaxTestTest.txt` or `/ajaxTestTest.txt`, leaving a leading `/`? If there was a `/` at the beginning that would make it look in the server's root dir instead of the current dir. `url:"ajaxTestText.txt"` should look for the file in the right place.